# cython build via setup.py does wrong thing (putting all .so files in extra src dir)

Tags: python, build, virtualenv, cython, distutils

I'm trying to convert from using pyximport to building via distutils, and I'm being stumped by the weird choices its making on where to put the .so files.  So, I decided to build the tutorial out of the cython doc, only to find it prints a message saying its building, but does nothng.  I'm in a virtualenv, and cython, python2.7, etc are all installed therein.

First the basics:

```
$ cython --version
Cython version 0.21.2
$ cat setup.py
from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize
print "hello build"
setup(
    ext_modules = cythonize("helloworld.pyx")
)
$ cat helloworld.pyx
print "hello world"
```

Now When I build it everything looks ok except for the extra src/src stuff in the output:

```
$ python setup.py build_ext --inplace
hello build
Compiling helloworld.pyx because it changed.
Cythonizing helloworld.pyx
running build_ext
building 'src.helloworld' extension
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c helloworld.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/helloworld.o
creating /home/henry/Projects/eyeserver/dserver/src/src
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -shared -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/helloworld.o -o /home/henry/Projects/eyeserver/dserver/src/src/helloworld.so
```

And when I run it, it of course fails:

```
$ echo "import helloworld" | python
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named helloworld
```

Until I move the .so file out of its extra src directory:

```
$ mv src/helloworld.so  .
$ echo "import helloworld" | python
Hello world
```

What am I doing wrong?  Obviously I could make the build process move all of the .so files, but that seems really hacky.

Comment: I cannot reproduce with `python-2.7.6` and `cython-0.21.2` on an osx machine.

Comment: Why is your .so file in a `src` directory? Where did that directory come from. You never mention that in your setup.

Comment: BTW, even if I move `helloworld.pyx` into a "src" directory inside the project and change the cythonize line in `setup.py` accordingly by using `src/helloword.pyx`, it still puts the .so file in the project's base directory. I think there must be something more to your project setup.

Comment: It's hard to answer without full text of `setup.py` and knowledge about your project file tree. I guess to take a look on `setup.py` from [aiohttp](https://github.com/KeepSafe/aiohttp/blob/master/setup.py#L19) -- the library use Cython to build `./aiohttp/_multidict.pyx` optional C Accelerator.

Comment: my setup.py is included above -- notice the cat setup.py above

Comment: @fnl -- that's the question -- why is it putting my .so files in an extra src directory.  I don't mention src anywhere!!!  The project itself is in a src directory, as you can see from the build output...

Comment: @HenryCrutcher cannot reproduce. Did you try to use virtualenv? Do you have `setup.cfg` in your project's folder?

Comment: I have no setup.cfg -- just the files displayed...  If nobody can repro I may just try not using a virtual env, or do something like that, or hold my nose and make the moving the .so files part of the build procedure....

Comment: @HenryCrutcher I use Cython for many projects and never did see your issue. Perhaps there is some weird spike in your local environment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Whenever I use cython I use the `Extension` command.

I would write the setup.py file as follows:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Build import cythonize

extensions = [
    Extension("helloworld", ["helloworld.pyx"])
]

setup(
    ext_modules = cythonize(extensions)
)
```

Hopefully this will then put the .so file in the current directory.

Comment: Extensions seems not to be defined when I run your setup file as given -- what am I doing wrong.  Importing distutils.core.Extensions doesn't work either...

Comment: You need to do `from distutils.extension import Extension`, not from core. Here is a good [setup.py example](https://github.com/syllog1sm/redshift/blob/master/setup.py) for a Cython project.

Comment: There is a typo in the call to `Extension` (extra "s"). Tried to edit the post, but I have to edit at least 6 characters :S.